# Count call answered within certain ranges 0 to 10 sec, group by count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, range, intervals

I need to count call answered within certain ranges 0 to 10 sec, 0 to 20 sec, etc. The count will increase while the delta will be the different count between the current and the next. The % will be the current count / the final count total.

Here is the sqlfiddle that you can use with data for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/803d2/2

Sample table of callsdetails:

```
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| id  | callid         | callerno | duration | status        |
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
| 634 | 1479097551.228 | 1000     |        2 | complete      |
| 635 | 1479102518.248 | 1000     |       12 | complete      |
+-----+----------------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Ranges                 | Count    | Delta    |    %     | 
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Between 0 to 10 secs   |       44 | +44      |  84.62 % |
| Between 0 to 20 secs   |       48 | +4       |  92.31 % |
| Between 0 to 30 secs   |       50 | +2       |  96.15 % |
| Between 0 to 40 secs   |       51 | +1       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 50 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 60 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 70 secs   |       51 | +0       |  98.08 % |
| Between 0 to 80 secs   |       52 | +1       | 100.00 % |
| Between 0 to 90 secs   |       52 | +0       | 100.00 % |
| Between 0 to 100+ secs |       52 | +0       | 100.00 % |
+------------------------+----------+----------+----------+
Total                            52
```

What I am able to create now is below query, if you can help to provide better solution, please advice. The problem that I face now is (Priority) I am not able to get the count and (secondary) the final count total (52) for the %, now I manually put in the final count total (52). Please help.

```
SELECT Ranges,Delta,ROUND(Delta/52*100,2) AS '%'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    (
        IF(duration<=10,'10',IF(duration<=20,'20',IF(duration<=30,'30',
        IF(duration<=40,'40',IF(duration<=50,'50',
        IF(duration<=60,'60',IF(duration<=70,'70',IF(duration<=80,
        '80',IF(duration<=90,'90','100+')))))))))) 
        AS Ranges,COUNT(duration) AS Delta
        FROM callsdetails
        GROUP BY Ranges
    ) a
GROUP BY Ranges;
```

Current Result:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| Ranges | Delta | %     |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 10     |    44 | 84.62 |
| 20     |     4 |  7.69 |
| 30     |     2 |  3.85 |
| 40     |     1 |  1.92 |
| 80     |     1 |  1.92 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: You could just `UNION` a total count to the bottom. also how does the original table look like?

Comment: I have add in sample table above for reference to original table. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem then you just want **ROLLUP** grouping funtion in mysql

your query

```
SELECT Ranges,Delta,ROUND(Delta/52*100,2) AS '%'
FROM
(
SELECT 
(
IF(duration<=10,'10',IF(duration<=20,'20',IF(duration<=30,'30',
IF(duration<=40,'40',IF(duration<=50,'50',
IF(duration<=60,'60',IF(duration<=70,'70',IF(duration<=80,
'80',IF(duration<=90,'90','100+')))))))))) 
AS Ranges,COUNT(duration) AS Delta
FROM callsdetails
GROUP BY Ranges
) a
GROUP BY Ranges WITH ROLLUP;
```

[FOR MORE REFERENCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: Hi denny, thanks for the info. Can you take at look the "current result" above, how do I add in the "Count" that will be increasing at each range like in the "expected result" as this is where should be the total that is needed. 

Now when I run the query, it adds in 1 new row at bottom.
| NULL |     1 |  1.92 |

Also does ROLLUP can only be used to show the total? I can't use the value for %?
% formula is the current count / the final count total.

Thanks again for your help, please advice if you know.

Comment: Give me sqlfiddle

Comment: Hi denny, here is the sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/803d2/1 let me know if you have better solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi denny, here is the sqlfiddle. sqlfiddle.com/#!9/803d2/1 let me know if you have better solution. Thanks for your help.